# Angular2 [ngClass] - Combining direct binding with conditional classes

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

I currently have two different working implementations of `[ngClass]` on an element;

```
[ngClass]="{ selected: element.isSelected, highlighted: element.isHighlighted}"
```

and

```
[ngClass]="element.customClasses"
```

Is it possible to combine both of these approaches in the template, or do I have to create a method in my component to return an array of classes based on the logic above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I opted for using `[class.*]` to set the conditional classes, leaving `[ngClass]` to handle the binding;

```
<div 
  [ngClass]="element.customClasses" 
  [class.selected]="element.isSelected"
  [class.highlighted]="element.isHighlighted"
></div>
```

Comment: Is the pattern of binding both to `ngClass` and a class property officially supported?  I ask because https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15396#issuecomment-293602762 claims that `<div class="some-class-{{someVariable}}" [class.new-class]="true">` didn't work, and the implication was that the `class` binding may overwrite the other.  In your example, I wonder if `class.selected` and/or `class.highlighted` might get clobbered sometimes by the `ngClass`.

Comment: I think there's a difference between manually concatenating classnames in html (avoid), and using Angular's binding methods as above. I'd expect there to be issues with the former. Both methods above however work together fine, not sure what takes precedence if the `highlighted` class were to be also included in the binding to `ngClass` though.

Comment: It works there's a test for it.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4a426696c98b28d20175cc3244ffa8b8b703790f/packages/common/test/directives/ng_class_spec.ts#L319

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the **customClasses** to your template as

```
<span class="customClasses">something</span>
```

And also you can use **[ngClass]** which will append your classes based on the condition, so putting together

```
<span [ngClass]="{ selected: element.isSelected, 
                 highlighted: element.isHighlighted}" 
                 class="customClasses">something
</span>
```

Comment: I opted for retaining the binding in `[ngClass]` and using `[class.selected]="element.isSelected"` etc to avoid updating `class`, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: but you had multiple conditions?

Comment: Yep, so I added multiple classes. It looks clearer that way IMO.

Comment: in order to reduce that only this **ngClass** attribute is created. your code will not be clean. anyways it is upto you. Thank you

Comment: Putting bindings directly within the native `class` attribute seems far less sensible than using Angular's directives though, surely. How exactly is it not clean? It's clearer.